# How can I update this custom Picker animation and transition to iOS 15?

Tags: swiftui, transition, deprecation-warning, ios-animations

The code beloew works well up to iOS 15, but now I'm getting the warning `'animation' was deprecated in iOS 15.0: Use withAnimation or animation(_:value:) instead.`

Looking around, it appears I should use `.animation(_, value: someValue)` - that does get rid of the warning, but then the code does not animate properly. I suppose it has to do with the picker being too fast? Or the picker influencing the `id` of the views?

This is the code that works, but of course, I'd prefer to keep it up-to-date with iOS 15:

```
struct SamplePickerSwap: View {
    let swapAnimation: Animation = .easeInOut(duration: 0.3333)
    let swapRight: AnyTransition = .asymmetric(
        insertion: .move(edge: .trailing),
        removal: .move(edge: .leading))
    let swapLeft: AnyTransition = .asymmetric(
        insertion: .move(edge: .leading),
        removal: .move(edge: .trailing))
    
    @State private var picker = 0
    @State private var segments = ["Left", "Right"]
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Picker("", selection: $picker) {
                ForEach(0 ..< segments.count) { index in
                    Text(self.segments[index])
                        .tag(index)
                }
            }
            .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
            
            switch picker {
                case 0:
                    Rectangle().fill(Color.green)
                        //.animation(swapAnimation, value: page) //This does not work
                        .animation(swapAnimation) // This is deprecated...
                        .transition(swapLeft)
                case 1:
                    Rectangle().fill(Color.yellow)
                        .animation(swapAnimation)
                        .transition(swapRight)
                default:
                    Rectangle().fill(Color.green)
                        .animation(swapAnimation) //
                        .transition(swapLeft)
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

I've tried adding another var `@State private var page = 0` and changing it with this:

```
            .onChange(of: picker, perform:  { _ in
                page = picker
            })
```

and using the iOS animation code of `.animation(swapAnimation, value: page)` or `.animation(swapAnimation, value: picker)` but no combination seems to work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We need to add animation to container (`VStack` in this case) to make subviews animated, like

```
    VStack {
        Picker("", selection: $picker) {
            ForEach(0 ..< segments.count) { index in
                Text(self.segments[index])
                    .tag(index)
            }
        }
        .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())

        switch picker {
        case 0:
            Rectangle().fill(Color.green)
                .transition(swapLeft)
        case 1:
            Rectangle().fill(Color.yellow)
                .transition(swapRight)
        default:
            Rectangle().fill(Color.green)
                .transition(swapLeft)
        }
        Spacer()
    }
    .animation(swapAnimation, value: picker) // << here !!
```

Tested with Xcode 13 / iOS 15

[image: demo]